# Flink python job execution fails

Tags: python, apache-flink

I have a flink cluster with 3 nodes set up. In the web interface I see 3 Task Managers, 3 Task Slots and 3 Available Task Slots.

I'm trying to run a simple word count and it fails very deterministically two out of three times. I assume that it fails every time it's not running on the master.

Here are my [`flink-conf.yaml`](https://pastebin.com/0n2esnws) and [`word_count.py`](https://pastebin.com/4jRkvmai) files.

The exception I'm getting is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Plan file caused an error. Check log-files for details.python: can't open file '/data/tmp/flink/flink-dist-cache-9fc4a122-1f21-4930-a998-db31129b4596/a68369119ce030c8ca4a0b98aeb39387/flink_dc/plan.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

(Full execution with stack trace is [here](https://pastebin.com/6zWb8ynP).)

I checked all the folders and they all have a `rwx` permission.

Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: which Flink version are you using? You may have to set the python.dc.tmp.dir parameter to point to some file-system location that is accessible by all nodes (like hdfs).

Comment: @ChesnaySchepler That's it! Thank you! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it. Also, do you know where can I find a list of "hidden/non documented" configuration variables? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the python.dc.tmp.dir parameter to point to some file-system location that is accessible by all nodes (like hdfs).

You can find all configuration options for the Python API here: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-libraries/flink-python/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/python/api/PythonOptions.java

Answer (score 0):

I have found a wordcount simpe flink.

He just run $ ./bin/flink run examples/streaming/WordCount.jar
for mor detail .jar content can be found on
https://bckinfo.com/applications/how-to-install-apache-flink-on-centos-8/

i hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).